# Im trying to dump the contents of a variable being called asychronously

Tags: php

The function looks like this:

```
public function insert_record($table, $dataobject) {
  $dataobject = (array)$dataobject;

  $columns = $this->get_columns($table);
  $cleaned = array();

  $fp = fopen('../../data.txt', 'w');

    foreach ($dataobject as $field => $value) {
      //fwrite($fp,  print_r($field), print_r($value) );
      // fwrite($fp,  print($field), print($value) );
      // fwrite($fp, var_export($value) );
    }

  fclose($fp);
}
```

I am trying, and failing miserably, to see inside the $dataobject variable. I am writing to a file because this function is called asynchronously and so I cannot break and var_dump().

Any ideas how I can look/dump/print/echo the contents of that variable?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the free dBug class available here: http://dbug.ospinto.com/  I've found it an invaluable debugging tool.  It will graphically break out any type of variable so you can see what's inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like XDebug.

http://xdebug.org/